# Permission denied errors on a file while executing it

Tags: unix, permissions, permission-denied

I get the following error everytime I try to execute

Error:-

```
/usr/bin/python: can't open file '/local/mnt/workspace/scrit1.py': [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

Permissions shown below:-

```
username3@buildserver:/local/mnt/workspace$ getfacl script1.py
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: local/mnt/workspace/script1.py
# owner: username1
# group: users
user::rwx
user:username2:rwx               #effective:r--
group::---
mask::r--
other::---

username3@qca-cdit-03:/local/mnt/workspace$ getfacl script2.py
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: local/mnt/workspace/script2.py
# owner: username1
# group: users
user::rwx
group::r--
other::r--
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty trivial case---as the permissions show you don't have the permission to execute that file.

But,there is a workaround to execute that file! You anyhow need to have root/admin privileges to be able to execute that file. You can use `sudo` command to execute that file with root privilege.

**NOTE :-** But,to have this command working you must be a sudoer and your username must be present in `/etc/sudoer` list! If not then you can consult admin to include you in sudoers list.

So,if you are a `sudoer`,then try doing this :-

```
$ sudo ./script1.py
```

It'll ask for `your` password! Please enter the same.

```
Enter password :
```

And,lastly that script will run for sure!

Comment: @shekar - how to give execute permissions to script1.py so that everyone can run?

Comment: @user3682248-Simply do--->`chmod +x scripyname.py` OR `chmod 755 scriptname.py`!